# How to give action feedback with VoiceOver?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, accessibility, voiceover

I have custom UIControl subclass that acts as toggle button. When the user taps it the button toggles a feature on off.

VoiceOver reads the value and hint like suggested by Apple:

```
self.accessibilityValue = @"Toggle alarm on off";
self.accessibilityHint = @"Double-tap to toggle setting";
```

But when user double taps to goggle, VoiceOver says nothing. I noticed in Settings app VoiceOver speaks aloud things like "On", "Off". How do I tell VoiceOver to speak what happened?

Comment: Are you using `accessibilityValue` as `accessibilityLabel` or is it a typo?

Comment: Doing it exactly as shown in this examples: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Accessibility_on_iPhone/Accessibility_on_iPhone.html

Comment: Where do they set the value?

Comment: You are right. The screenshot with speech bubbles confused me.